# URL parameter rewrite or redirect as subdomain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I created a wild card domain.

My product page URL is:

```
http://www.example.com/add/productdetails/city/product_title/Product_ID
```

I want to rewrite above URL as:

```
http://www.city.example.com/add/productdetails/product_title/Product_ID
```

*with city name as a sub domain*.

Please help me configuring rewrite rule Website is in codeigniter

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/city\.example\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: city is dynamic parameter, it change according to product listing